# Is MUI5 tree view with MUI5 autocomplete integration possible?

Tags: material-ui

I have developed MUI5 Tree View with checked , unchecked and indeterminate state. I wanted to integrate this tree view with MUI5 autocomplete, I am wondering is this possible? if so how can i achieve this. any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MUI5 docs say that:

> @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

[docs](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/)

Unfortunately you need to migrate styles to supported and recommended ways: `sx` or `styled`.